# Upload multiple files one by one in angular(Loop through observables)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a backend rest api which accepts only single File to upload.
I have an angular app, which need to upload multiple files one by one. I tried with iterating over but it is failing since before completing the first upload, second is being upload and it is failing.

```
 upload() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.fileList.length - 1; i++) {

      // this.uploadObservableList.push( this.memberService
      //   .uploadCmsDocument(this.path, this.fileList[i]));

      console.log(`File ${this.fileList[i]}`);
      this.subscriptionList.push(
        this.memberService
          .uploadCmsDocument(this.path, this.fileList[i])
          .subscribe( {
            next: (res) => {
              this.notifyUpload.emit('UPLOAD_DONE');
            },
            error: (error) => {
              console.log(`error ${error}`);
            },
            complete: () => {
              console.log('Compelte');
            }
          }
            
 
     )
      );
    }
```

How to submit upload request and wait until it is done and fire next request ?. Is there any RXJS operator that i can use ?

I tried Rxjs concat, forkjoin but didnt work.

Below is the concat version that i tried:

Service call api:

```
uploadCmsDocument(path: string, file: File){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.backendServiceUrl}/content-data/documents?path=${path}`, formData);
  }
```

Component:

```
 export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input()
  path!: string;

  @Output()
  notifyUpload: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  @ViewChild('attachments') attachment: any;

  fileList: File[] = [];
  listOfFiles: any[] = [];
  subscriptionList: Subscription[] = [];
  uploadObservableList: Observable<any>[] =[];

  constructor(
    public memberService: MemberService,
    public cmsFileContentService: CmsFileContentService
  ) {}

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptionList.forEach((sub) => sub.unsubscribe());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('INtit');
  }

  upload() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.fileList.length - 1; i++) {
      this.uploadObservableList.push( this.memberService
        .uploadCmsDocument(this.path, this.fileList[i]));
    }

    
    concat(...this.uploadObservableList).
    pipe(catchError(error => of(error))).
    subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.notifyUpload.emit('UPLOAD_DONE');
    }
      );

    this.listOfFiles = [];
    this.fileList = [];
  }

  onFileChanged(event: any) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= event.target.files.length - 1; i++) {
      var selectedFile = event.target.files[i];
      this.fileList.push(selectedFile);
      this.listOfFiles.push(selectedFile.name);
    }

    //this.attachment.nativeElement.value = '';
  }

  removeSelectedFile(index: number) {
    // Delete the item from fileNames list
    this.listOfFiles.splice(index, 1);
    // delete file from FileList
    this.fileList.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

html file:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-2">
      <div class="file is-info">
        <label class="file-label">
          <input class="file-input" multiple type="file" multiple (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
          <span class="file-cta">
            <span class="file-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="file-label">
              Choose a file…
            </span>
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="column is-2">
      <button class="button is-info"  (click)="upload()">
        Upload
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <ng-container *ngFor="let selected of listOfFiles; let index = index">
   
                <div class="tags has-addons">
                <a class="tag is-link">{{ selected }}</a>
                <a class="tag is-delete" (click)="removeSelectedFile(index)"></a>
                </div>
 
  </ng-container>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: concat is the one. On this website, it's not enough to say "didn't work". You need to elaborate on that if you really want to get help.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Just updated how i tried concat operator

Comment: It looks OK, what is the outcome when you use concat?

Comment: You can maybe try to use the spread operator on that observable array, like this: `concat(...this.uploadObservableList)`

Comment: It didnt call the api call, instead emitted the UPLOAD_DONE

Comment: single file upload works with that. but multiple is failing again

Comment: concat(...this.uploadObservableList) this actuallly works but one the same page if i upload 5 files, it uploaded and then i upload 2 more files after that it fails

Comment: Is that something releated to subscription closing ?

Comment: Can you also include the implementation of the `uploadCmsDocument` method?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Updated question service api call

Comment: What type is `this.fileList` and how is it populated? Is it possible that only one file ever gets in there?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Updated full code html and component

Comment: *this actuallly works but one the same page if i upload 5 files, it uploaded and then i upload 2 more files after that it fails* this should be in the question with details. Perhaps you need to reset `this.uploadObservableList = []` after upload or you'll be reuploading the same files and this may fail?